# Unable to load dependencies in java project

Tags: micronaut, tron

I'm new to java, so sorry if my question seems silly to some. I am trying to add a library for working with the Tron blockchain network to the project dependencies (https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronj).

The instructions indicate that I need to add the maven repository                                  {
url "https://dl.bintray.com/tronj/tronj"
},  as well as 4 dependencies
`dependencies {
// protobuf & grpc
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.11.0'

```
implementation 'org.tron.tronj:abi:0.1.2'
implementation 'org.tron.tronj:client:0.1.2'
implementation 'org.tron.tronj:utils:0.1.2'

implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
```

}. `But my project gives 3 errors during build` Unresolved dependency: org.tron.tronj:abi:0.1.2Java(0)
Unresolved dependency: org.tron.tronj:client:0.1.2Java(0)
Unresolved dependency: org.tron.tronj:utils:0.1.2`

I tried to do everything clearly according to the instructions from the repository and the site https://tronjdocument.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mddocs/Quickstart.html, but the error still remains.

Comment: Did you also added repository mentioned in your link?

Comment: Yes, everything is according to the instructions, any other dependencies can be added without problems, it is tronj that does not work. I am using gradle but also tried using maven, same error

Comment: It looks like the client may be available at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.zlwl/tronj-client/1.0.2.  I don't know about the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

I checked repository link from your question and it looks like service is down

In Google i found this: https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/02/jfrog-jcenter-bintray-closure/

In this library github i found issue related to this fact but there is no reponse from authors: https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronj/issues/17

I can see that source code repositories is still on Github (https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronj) so if you really need this you can build this jar localy

Comment: Do you mean I can take the code that I need from there and use it in my project?

Comment: Looks like its Apache 2.0 license so you can (you can find more informations about licesnse on this library github) , but my proposition was to download this repo and build jar locally and then add this jar to your project